# Pattern (g)sub = a string within a column (R)

Tags: r, string, dataframe, gsub

I'm searching for a really long time now, but I can't figure out how to replace a substance of a string where the pattern is a string within a column and different for every row. So I have these data:

```
         var1                         var2                var3
"Sentence 1 is exiting, isnt it?"  "exiting"         
"Sentence 2 is boring, isnt it?"   "boring"
```

I eventually want this:

```
         var1                        var2                   var3
"Sentence 1 is exiting, isnt it?"  "exiting"         "Sentence 1 is, isnt it?"
"Sentence 2 is boring, isnt it?"   "boring"          "Sentence 2 is, isnt it?"
```

So in every row there is another pattern that needs to be replaced. If I do var3 = gsub(var2, "", var1) I get an error, because var2 is not an expression.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `mapply`:

```
df <- data.frame(var1= c("Sentence 1 is exiting, isnt it?","Sentence 2 is boring, isnt it?"), var2=c("exiting","boring"))


df$var3 <- mapply(gsub, pattern=df$var2, x=df$var1, replacement="")
```

`mapply` applies the function `gsub` to the first element of `pattern` and `x`, then to the second elements, etc.

Comment: I suppose that must work, but I get an error: "Error in (function (pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,  : 
  invalid regular expression '.......', reason 'Missing ')''. So inside of a string it is missing a ")". In the string there is indeed a "(", but no ")", but why would that be a problem? (The text contains a lot of white spaces and special characters). I will try to remove these....

Comment: If there are more specifics to your data, you should let us know. With the example you provided, my answer works.